# Installing jasperserver while skipping DB creation

Tags: jasperserver

I am installing jasperserver from within an external script with running

"./js-install.sh minimal"

But it stuck with these in the log:

> Database [] already exists. Drop it and create new? WARNING: All
>   existing data will be lost! This operation may not be rolled back.
>   Enter 'y' to recreate or 'n' to skip this step...

What can I do to make Jasper skip this (that is, to accept the default 'n') and continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should use

```
recreatejsDB=y
```

in `default_properties.master`, for `$systemname = js`.

To find out the systemname, one can see the log files where it is written in parameter `recreate<systemName>Db`.

Comment: this was useful when designing my puppet module to install jasper reports. Thank you.